# Azure DevOps Client Library - Download Earlier Repository Files

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to download earlier repository versions (.csproj files) from the commit records that I am obtaining from the Azure DevOps NuGet client library. I want to do this so I can access the Assembly Version information in the .csproj file. The GetFile() function I am using to get the current version of the file works fine but I want to download the older versions of the file from the commit records.

This is the GetFile function.

```
        public string GetFile(string projectName, string repoName, string fileName)
        {
            try
            {
                var items = ListItems(projectName, repoName);
                var projectPath = items.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Path.Contains(fileName))?.Path ?? "";

                GitHttpClient gitClient = GetGitHttpClient();
                GitRepository repo = GetRepositoryAsync(projectName, repoName);

                var stream = gitClient.GetItemTextAsync(repo.Id, projectPath).Result;
                var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
                return reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return "";
            }
        }
```

And this function gets the commits.

```
        public async Task<List<GitCommitRef>> GetCommitsAsync(string projectName, string repoName)
        {
            var client = GetGitHttpClient();
            var repo = GetRepositoryAsync(projectName, repoName);
            var gitQueryCommitsCriteria = new GitQueryCommitsCriteria();
            return await client.GetCommitsAsync(repo.Id, gitQueryCommitsCriteria);
        }
```

Now I want to download each version of the .csproj that relates to each of these commits.

Any help anyone can give me with this would be greatly appreciated.

Kind regards, Stuart

Comment: Just a reminder. If you develop it in Visual Studio, you can use F12 in functions to see its metadata.

Comment: Hi friend, is there any update for this issue? Does it still block you?

Answer (score 0):

> The GetFile() function I am using to get the current version of the
>   file works fine but I want to download the older versions of the file
>   from the commit records.

I think you're in the right direction. I once used `Azure Devops Rest Api` [Items-Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/items/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) to get content of one specific version of file successfully with the help of `versionDescriptor` parameter.

```
https://dev.azure.com/MyOrgName/MyProjectName/_apis/git/repositories/MyReposName/Items?path=/README.md&versionDescriptor%5BversionOptions%5D=0&versionDescriptor%5BversionType%5D=2&versionDescriptor%5Bversion%5D={Commit ID}&download=true&resolveLfs=true&%24format=octetStream&api-version=5.0-preview.1
```

Since functions available in client library are **corresponding to** that in Rest Api, so client library must have corresponding parameters to do that.

**And here's what I found:**

Most of the overloads of `gitClient.GetItemTextAsync()` functions have `GitVersionDescriptor versionDescriptor = null` as input, and I think this is what you need.

[image]

Hope it makes some help.